# Starting on a puppet Railo-jetty module and deploying it

Tags: jetty, puppet, railo, runit

I'm starting on writing a puppet module to install deploy and manage Railo with jetty using runit
... Any help would be greatly appreciated i know the basis of 
it should have ...
We need a zip file railo express

unpack the zip

tell the system to start the start.sh in the folder

keep it running and accessible through index.cfm page

stop the server by calling stop.sh in the directory

So to start Thanks

Comment: Ok like i need the basic resource structure for puppet to use?

Comment: It looks like Puppet has [comprehensive documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/) and [reference guides](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_resources.html) - spend some time reading through those and you should get the info you need.